Seeking DApps that use personal_sign, eth_signTypedData, and eth_signTypedData_v3 with ERC-1271 signature validation
I am currently working on a wallet and encountering challenges with testing signature verification locally. When using viem's verifyTypedData/verifyMessage methods in a local environment, I'm only able to test against the hashed message created by the wallet, which isn’t entirely reflective of a real-world scenario where the DApp itself creates the hashed message.
I was able to successfully test eth_signTypedData_v4 using Uniswap, which reflects a proper end-to-end implementation.
However, I'm struggling to find examples of DApps that use personal_sign, eth_signTypedData, and eth_signTypedData_v3 and also support ERC-1271 for signature validation. Does anyone know of any such DApps to properly test my implementation?

Here we go - https://github.com/WalletConnect/web-examples?tab=readme-ov-file
List of test dapps that cover many scenarios.

Avoid link only answers as link can die.
